# How to insert a checkbox in a given cell when one is deleted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to create a script that replaces checkboxes in given columns when they are deleted. Below is an image depicting my setup. I would like it so when a row is deleted only the columns with checkboxes will be replaced with checkboxes again.

[Image of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pnvA.jpg)

I am looking to replace only the labeled columns with checkboxes once deleted. Unfortunately Google Sheets has no way of preserving data validation once a user deletes it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome! Please show us what you've come up with, how it went, or what went wrong with your best attempts. See [ask]. If you make progress on your problem or if an answer is useful, [let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you need to revise the question, you can always correct it or add more info by clicking 'edit'. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a script re-add data validation for those ranges, if overwriting non-checkboxes would be dangerous. Again, this is naturally safer, and much faster since it does entire columns at once.

```
function checkboxes() {

  var targetSheetName = "Sheet1",
      headerRows = 1,
      checkboxColumns = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]; // UPDATE THIS LIST IF RESTRUCTURING SPREADSHEET

  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(targetSheetName),
      maxRows = targetSheet.getMaxRows(),
      targetRows = maxRows - headerRows,
      enforceCheckbox = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
  enforceCheckbox.requireCheckbox();
  enforceCheckbox.setAllowInvalid(false);
  enforceCheckbox.build();

  for (var c in checkboxColumns) {
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(headerRows+1, checkboxColumns[c], targetRows);
    targetRange.setDataValidation(enforceCheckbox);
  }
}
```

If you instead don't care about contents of those columns, this will forcibly overwrite non-checkboxes with checkboxes. It's much slower though because it goes cell by cell to preserve checkboxes and overwrite everything else.

```
function checkboxes() {

  var targetSheetName = "Sheet1",
      headerRows = 1,
      checkboxColumns = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]; // UPDATE THIS LIST IF RESTRUCTURING SPREADSHEET

  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(targetSheetName),
      maxRows = targetSheet.getMaxRows(),
      targetRows = maxRows - headerRows;

  for (var c in checkboxColumns) {
    for (var r = headerRows + 1; r <= maxRows; r++) {    
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(r, checkboxColumns[c]);
      if (targetRange.isChecked() == null) {
        targetRange.insertCheckboxes();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that `false == null`. So any unchecked checkboxes get overwritten

Comment: Indeed. And while we're noting things: true == checked(). [Perhaps it's just me in this situation but] if you ever find your Sheets have cells set to true, they would *become a checked box*.